# Consistent way to overlay data on histogram (extracting the binned data from geom_histogram?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

My goal is to create this plot in ggplot2:

[image: horizontal histogram with data entries filling up the histogram]

After a lot of fiddling around, I managed to create it for this one dataset, as per the screenshot above, with the following rather fragile code (note the `width=63, boundary=410`, which took lots of trial and error):

```
ex = data.frame(year=c(1971,1973,1975,1977,1979,1981,1983,1985,1987,1989,1991,1993,1995,1997,1999,2001,2003,2005,2007,2009,2011,2013,2015,2017,2019), occurances=c(347,773,589,462,280,455,1037,707,663,746,531,735,751,666,642,457,411,286,496,467,582,577,756,557,373))
ex_bin = mutate(ex, range=cut_width(occurances, width=63, boundary=410)) # bin the data
ex_bin$lower = as.numeric(sub("[\\(\\[](.+),.*", "\\1", ex_bin$range)) # extract range lower bound
ex_bin$upper = as.numeric(sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", ex_bin$range)) # extract range upper bound
ex_bin$pos = as.numeric(rbind(by(ex_bin, seq_len(nrow(ex_bin)), function(ey) count(ex_bin[ex_bin$year <= ey$year & ex_bin$upper == ey$upper, ])))[1,]) # extract our visual x position, based on the number of years already in this bin
ggplot(ex_bin, aes(x=occurances, fill=year==2019)) +coord_flip() + geom_histogram(binwidth = 63, boundary=410) + geom_text(color="white", aes(label=year, x=(upper+lower)/2, y=pos-0.5, group=year), ex_bin) # plot!
```

Do note the hardcoded boundary and binwidth. This is very fragile, and has to be tweaked to work on a per-dataset basis. How can I get this to consistently work? I'm less concerned about highlighting a chosen year (2019 here, just to show the misalignment in the bins) than I am with correct label placement. My earlier attempts with `stat_bin`, `cut_number`, `bins=13`, and other approaches all ended up with misaligned plots looking like this (I've switched from `text` to `label` to show the alignment errors more clearly):

[image: horizontal histogram with non-aligned labels]

```
ex_bin = mutate(ex, range=cut_number(occurances, n=13)) # I've also tried cut_interval
ex_bin$lower = as.numeric(sub("[\\(\\[](.+),.*", "\\1", ex_bin$range))
ex_bin$upper = as.numeric(sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", ex_bin$range))
ex_bin$pos = as.numeric(rbind(by(ex_bin, seq_len(nrow(ex_bin)), function(ey) count(ex_bin[ex_bin$year <= ey$year & ex_bin$upper == ey$upper, ])))[1,])
ggplot(ex_bin, aes(x=occurances, fill=year==2019)) +coord_flip() + geom_histogram(bins=13) + geom_label(color="white", aes(label=year, x=(upper+lower)/2, y=pos-0.5, group=year), ex_bin)
```

Why? Is there some way I can extract and use the same data as `geom_histogram`? I attempted to read the ggplot code, but I wasn't able to make sense of the execution flow. To further add to the confusion, playing with the label placement code often also re-binned the `geom_histogram`, even if it was using the original data frame. This surprised me as each tweak to the labels would screw up the placement because the histogram would then move again (note the three years in bins below the highlighted bin, vs the two above):

[image: horizontal histogram with non-aligned labels over different bins]

```
ex_bin = mutate(ex, range=cut_width(occurances, width=63, boundary=410))
ex_bin$lower = as.numeric(sub("[\\(\\[](.+),.*", "\\1", ex_bin$range))
ex_bin$upper = as.numeric(sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", ex_bin$range))
ex_bin$pos = as.numeric(rbind(by(ex_bin, seq_len(nrow(ex_bin)), function(ey) count(ex_bin[ex_bin$year <= ey$year & ex_bin$upper == ey$upper, ])))[1,])
ggplot(ex_bin, aes(x=occurances, fill=year==2019)) +coord_flip() + geom_histogram(bins=13) + geom_label(color="white", aes(label=year, x=(upper+lower)/2, y=pos-0.5, group=year), ex_bin)
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I make this plot type work consistently by specifying `bins=13` or similar? Is there an simpler/easier way to do this?
2. Why is the the `geom_histogram` so slippery, re-binning based on "unrelated" code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `stat="bin"` in `geom_text` too. Additionally we have to `group` by year so that each year is a separate "block". The tricky part is to get the year labels for which I make use of `after_stat`. However, as the `group`s are stored internally as an integer sequence we have them back to the corresponding years for which I make use of a helper vector.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ex <- data.frame(year = c(1971, 1973, 1975, 1977, 1979, 1981, 1983, 1985, 1987, 1989, 1991, 1993, 1995, 1997, 1999, 2001, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019), 
                occurances = c(347, 773, 589, 462, 280, 455, 1037, 707, 663, 746, 531, 735, 751, 666, 642, 457, 411, 286, 496, 467, 582, 577, 756, 557, 373))

years <- levels(factor(ex$year))
                
ggplot(ex, aes(y = occurances, fill = year == 2019, group = as.character(year), label = year)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 63, boundary = 410, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(color = "white", aes(label = after_stat(if_else(count > 0, as.character(years[group]), ""))), stat = "bin", 
            binwidth = 63, boundary = 410, position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

**EDIT** The approach also works fine when using `bins` instead of `binwidth` and `boundary`:

```r
ggplot(ex, aes(y = occurances, fill = year == 2019, group = as.character(year), label = year)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=13, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(color = "white", aes(label = after_stat(if_else(count > 0, as.character(years[group]), ""))), stat = "bin", 
            bins=13, position = position_stack(vjust = .5, reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was not aware of `after_stat` with `count` and not `..count..` is there a difference? I got pretty close by attempting to use if_else, but why is `after_stat` required? Also, can the fragile `binwidth = 63, boundary = 410` be replaced with `bins=13` or similar?

Comment: Not much difference. `after_stat` is simply the new approach and meant to replace the old approach using `..`. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html. Concerning your second question. For sure does this work with `bins`. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

We can pre-compute our bins with fixed length, then plot with tiles:

```
# make fixed length bins, see length.out=10
d <- ex %>% 
  mutate(X = cut(occurances, seq(min(occurances) - 1, max(occurances) + 1, length.out = 10))) %>%
  group_by(X) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(Y = row_number())
           
#plot with tiles
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = Y, label = year, fill = year == 2019)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** Create pretty breaks for x-axis, and adjust vline to match x-axis:

```
# set the sequence breaks
seqBy = 100
rr = range(ex$occurances)
cutBreaks <- seq(from = rr[ 1 ] %/% seqBy * seqBy,
                 to = (rr[ 2 ] + seqBy) %/% seqBy * seqBy, 
                 by = seqBy)

# adjust vline to match factors on X axis
vline <- 650
vlineAdjust <- findInterval(vline, cutBreaks) + vline %% seqBy / seqBy
  
# convert X to factor
d <- ex %>% 
  mutate(X = cut(occurances, breaks = cutBreaks, dig.lab = 5)) %>%
  group_by(X) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(Y = row_number())

#plot with tiles
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = Y, label = year, fill = year == 2019)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_text() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = vlineAdjust, col = "blue") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, no magic numbers! `row_number` in the group is just the solution to the awkward counting I was attempting to do. However, is there a way to make the x axis linear again so I can use `geom_vline`, etc? or at the very least have nicer labels, even if they don't correspond to bins?

Comment: @byteit101 see Edit, you can change *seqBy* and *vline* as per your needs.